# conditional count in php mysql for one column

Tags: php, sql

i want to count all buy and sell in x duration. i have tried the following query, but its not giving the correct result.

```
select pair, duration, mode,
       count(case when mode='BUY' then 1 else 0 end) as BUYS,
       count(case when mode='SELL' then 1 else 0 end) as SELLS
from trends
where pair like 'EURAUD '
GROUP BY DURATION, MODE
ORDER BY MODE, DURATION
 duration | mode|BUYS|SELLS
 -------------------------
 1Dy      | BUY | 1  | 1
 1M       | BUY | 18 | 18
 1Wk      | BUY | 1  | 1
 5M       | BUY | 3  | 3
 15M      | SELL| 2  | 2
 1Hr      | SELL| 1  | 1
 1M       | SELL| 25 | 25
 30M      | SELL| 1  | 1
 5M       | SELL| 4  | 4
```

its showing the above result, thats not correct. it show the following result

```
 duration | mode|BUYS|SELLS
 -------------------------
 1Dy      | BUY | 1  | 0
 1M       | BUY | 18 | 0
 1Wk      | BUY | 1  | 0
 5M       | BUY | 3  | 0
 15M      | SELL| 0  | 4
 1Hr      | SELL| 0  | 1
 1M       | SELL| 0  | 25
 30M      | SELL| 0  | 1
 5M       | SELL| 0  | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `sum()`, not `count()`:

```
select pair, duration, mode,
       sum(case when mode = 'BUY' then 1 else 0 end) as BUYS,
       sum(case when mode = 'SELL' then 1 else 0 end) as SELLS
from trends
where pair like 'EURAUD '
GROUP BY DURATION, MODE
ORDER BY MODE, DURATION;
```

`COUNT()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  Your `case` expression never returns `NULL`, so the count always returns the same values.  I prefer using `SUM()` anyways.

Comment: actually i have one column name mode, and it has "BUY" or "SELL", so i cant sum :(

Comment: @asifhameed . . . The `case` expression is being summed.